# Direct Sum on Homology

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

I have a big problem and i don't know how to solve it i have no idea

So, let $i_2: X_2\rightarrow X$ an inclusion and $j_1: X\rightarrow (X,X_1)$ we have that $i_{2_*}: H_k(X_2)\rightarrow H_k(X)$ is injective and $j_{1_*}\circ i_{2_*}: H_k(X_2)\rightarrow H_k(X,X_1)$ is an isomorphism, so in the proof they say that because $i_{2_*}$ is injective then we have : $$H_k(X)=\ker j_{1_*}\oplus \text{Im}~ i_{2_*}$$

this is the proposition and the proof please help me:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

What book is it you are quoting?

- You need to consider the excision property (if you are to follow the given proof), which is given e.g. in Theorem 2.17 and Corollary 2.18 of the following links:
  http://www.math.toronto.edu/mgualt/MAT1300/Week%206-9%20Term%202.pdf
- The idea is to use the 5-lemma to show the desired isomorphism.
- Alternatively, one may show directly that $H_k(X)=H_k(X_1)\oplus H_k(X_2)$ simply because $X_1, X_2$ are a disjoint union and every singular simplex $\sigma:\Delta^k \to X$ is such that its image falls within $X_1$ or $X_2$ (use connectedness of the simplex).  Likewise with $A$ and $A_i=A \cap X_i.$

Actually, it is all done here (if you use the 5-lemma):
[Homology of disjoint union is direct sum of homologies](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56286/homology-of-disjoint-union-is-direct-sum-of-homologies?rq=1)

---

You have $X=X_1 \sqcup X_2$ union of two disjoint subsets.  In fact, by excision you have (here $S_*$ denotes the complex of singular chains of a space or of a pair) a canonical morphism

$$S_*(X_2)=S_*(X_2,\emptyset) \to S_*(X, X_1)$$ which is an isomorphism.  If you write the exact sequence of relative homology (before taking homology, i.e. at the level of singular chains) you have

$$0\to S_*(X_1) \to S_*(X) \to S_*(X, X_1) \cong S_*(X_2) \to 0,$$ by the above.  You can exchange both $X_1$ and $X_2$, and that means that the above exact sequence splits, i.e.

$$S_*(X)=S_*(X_1)\oplus S_*(X_2)$$  (there are other ways to do this, but let's leave it).

Likewise with $A$ and $A_i$.  The direct sums you're looking for are there.

Comment: D. Motreanu, V.V. Motreanu, and N. Papageorgiou,
Topological and Variational Methods with Applications to Nonlinear Boundary Value Problems, Springer, 2014.

Comment: is methode given bye @MattN is correct in :http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56286/homology-of-disjoint-union-is-direct-sum-of-homologies?rq=1   ? please

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand how we find $\ker j_{1_*}$ and $\text{Im}~i_{2_*}$ in direct somme using excision, please give me more details

Comment: The property of excesion just tel us that $H_k(X_2)\simeq H_k(X,X_1)$ what is the exact sequence witch give us that $H_k(X)=\ker j_{1_*}\oplus \text{Im}~i_{2_*}$ ? please please help me

Comment: This not the disered answer .......

Comment: I have added some more details, but there is no replacement to a proper study of the tools.

Comment: The answer given in the link you provide is good, indeed (and simpler than the provided in the first reference).